# How to do a dependsOn clause on multiple firewall rule collection groups in ARM?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to deploy an arm template that will create a firewall policy and add MULTIPLE firewall rule collection groups (All in one script). However, I keep running into this error when I deploy my pipeline:
[image: pipeline error]

I understand that I am running into this error because the firewall policy is stuck in a "updating" provisioning state when it is creating the first rule collection group and that prevents from completing then next one.

However, I'm not sure how / if it is possible to use a dependsOn statement in ARM based off of a rule collection group. I had a dependsOn statement based off the firewall policy for each rule collection group - but this would cause the same error to occur after the first rule collection group was created.

Any help or suggestions on getting this done in ARM would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: SOLUTION:

After poking around and trying different things for a few hours, I was able to find a way out to make it work. My dependsOn clause looked like this:

"dependsOn": [
"[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/firewallPolicies/ruleCollectionGroups', variables('firewallPolicyName'),'RuleCollectionGroupName')]"
],

Where **'RuleCollectionGroupName'** is the name of the rule group that you want the dependsOn clause to wait on. I wasn't able to find this anywhere online for ARM template and saw others run into this issue too. Hopefully this helps others.

Comment: Are you trying to deploy this through pipeline only? @powertester19

Comment: @Jahnavi Ideally, yes